# Flushing the Android Bluetooth name cache

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to write some code which does Bluetooth device discovery.

Android keeps a cache of the friendly names for Bluetooth devices: calling `BluetoothDevice.getName()` returns the value in the cache, or `null` if the name is not cached yet.

I'm trying to test the code path for when no name is available. Unfortunately this is really hard, as the cache is persistent. Once Android has seen a device once, it's cached and I never see Android try to look up the name again.

Is there any way to flush the name cache to force Android to refetch the names --- and, most importantly, report that the name is unavailable while doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question [How to programmatically clear the Bluetooth name cache in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793761/how-to-programmatically-clear-the-bluetooth-name-cache-in-android) is very similar to your question, and may be of help to you.